# sorting a gridview bound to a linq SP

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting, gridview

I have a grid bound to a linqed SP thus:

```
Session["results"] = db.spGetCaseByNumberOrSurname(txtCaseNum.Text.Trim(), null).ToList();
gvResults.DataSource = Session["results"];
```

on the sorting of it, i would like to be able to do this..

```
    protected void gvResults_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        List<spGetCaseByNumberOrSurnameResult> data = Session["results"] as List<spGetCaseByNumberOrSurnameResult>;
        if (sd == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            sd = SortDirection.Descending;
            gvResults.DataSource = data.OrderBy(d => d.GetType().GetProperty(sortExpression));
        }
        else
        {
            sd = SortDirection.Ascending;
            gvResults.DataSource = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.GetType().GetProperty(sortExpression));
        }
        gvResults.DataBind();
    }
```

sadly that doesnt do any sorting at all..it in fact errors with
"The data source does not support server-side data paging."

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d.GetType().GetProperty(sortExpression)` returns a [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z852kf5.aspx) object. What you need is the value of the property like this:

```
d.GetType().GetProperty(sortExpression).GetValue(d, null);
```